# More detailed Link to install hbase and hadoop on ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am going to install hadoop and HBase on ubuntu. when I tried to search any good link then I was unable to find which is fully clear and more descriptive. I need a detailed link from which I can easily set up hsdoop and hbase.
Thanks

Comment: You might find this helpful Install <a href="http://www.technology-mania.com/2012/11/hbase-soft-introduction-quickstart.html">HBase on Ubuntu </a> Install <a href="http://www.technology-mania.com/2011/03/hadoop-in-pseudo-distributed-mode.html"> Hadoop on Ubuntu (single node) </a>

Comment: You can check [this one](http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2014/06/gettint-started-with-hbase.html) for detailled installation and how to write Java-based clients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't mention either you want to set up these in pseudo distributed mode or multi distributed OR single-node or multi-node . Anyway here are some links which would be helpful for you
[hadoop single node cluster](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) , 
[hadoop multi node cluster](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) , 
and for hbase , I think you should see these links
[install HBase in pseudo distributed mode](http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/setup-hbase-in-pseudo-distributed-mode-and-connect-java-client/) , 
[hbase installation in fully distributed mode](http://hbase.apache.org/book/standalone_dist.html)

Hope it will help you - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For psuedo distributed mode I would suggest the following links

HADOOP INSTALLATION
http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/hadoop_installation.php

HBASE INSTALLATION
http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/hbase_installation.php